# Flutter Problem Dynamic Link opens the app inside whatsapp

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

When the link is opened via whatsapp, an instance of the app is opened inside whatsapp, if the app is later opened by the launcher.
2 instances of the same app are open, one by whatsapp the other by the app itself.

Steps to reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1 - Generate the link and send it to whatsapp.
2 - Click the link on whatsapp

Expected behavior
It is expected that after the click, the app will be opened outside of whatsapp

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink().then((value){
    if (value != null){
        if (value.link.queryParameters["challenge_id"] != null){
            DesafioModel desafioModel = DesafioModel();
            desafioModel.id = value.link.queryParameters["challenge_id"];
            Get.offNamed("$CHALLENGE_DETAILS_ROUTE", arguments: desafioModel);
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: add android:launchMode="singleTask" inside activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks, I've already done that, but I forgot to update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others who need it, as Jiten Basnet noted in the comments, the solution is to add

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

inside activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Define the launchMode in AndroidManifest.xml file as singleTask, then there will be only one instance and it will not be in any app. Your app will open separately.

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

For more info, checkout this : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack